# Why is the LED blinking without any physical interrupt?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

The following is the interrupt handler for LED0 to toggle when an interrupt occurs on the UART0 due to LIN transmission from master to slave, my device is the slave. But without connecting my device(slave) to the master that means without any LIN transmission over UART, the LED0 is toggling. I cannot understand, how can this happen automatically? How can an interrupt be generated and Toggle of LED0 can happen?

```
void FTM0_IRQHandler()
  {     
    if (1==((FTM0_C0SC & FTM_CnSC_CHF_MASK)>>FTM_CnSC_CHF_SHIFT) )  /* If the CHF of the channel is equal to 0 */
    {
        (void)FTM0_C0SC;                            /* Read to clear flag */
        FTM0_C0SC ^= FTM_CnSC_CHF_MASK;             /* Clear flag */
        FTM0_C0V = FTM0_C0V + 391 ; /* Refresh interrupt period */

        if (LED_counter>=50){
            /* Toggle LED for LIN transmission */
            /* Reset counter */
            LED0_TOGGLE;
            LED_counter = 0;
        }
        LED_counter++;
    }
  }
```

In my main funtion I have called my timer initialization as follows:

```
lin_application_timer_FTM0();
```

And the above function is defined as follows:

```
void lin_application_timer_FTM0()
{
    SIM_SCGC |= SIM_SCGC_FTM0_MASK; /* Enable Clock for FTM0 */         
    FTM0_SC |= FTM_SC_PS(7);    /* Select Preescaler in this case 128. 20 Mhz /128 =156.25 Khz. */ 
                                    /* Counter increase by one every 6.4 us */      
        /* Enable Channle 0*/
    FTM0_C0SC |= FTM_CnSC_CHIE_MASK; /* Enable channel 0 interrupt */
    FTM0_C0SC |= FTM_CnSC_MSA_MASK;  /* Channel as Output compare mode */           
        /*Select interrupt frequency*/
    FTM0_C0V = FTM_CnV_VAL(391) ;       /* Interrupt every 2.5ms */ 

    FTM0_SC |= FTM_SC_CLKS(1); /*FTM0 use system clock*/

        /* Set the ICPR and ISER registers accordingly */
    NVIC_ICPR |= 1 << ((INT_FTM0-16)%32);
    NVIC_ISER |= 1 << ((INT_FTM0-16)%32);
}
```

Can anyone explain why is the LED0 toggling without any interrupt?

Comment: Which embedded system is this, specifically?

Comment: Where's the part that uses the UART? All I see is a timer interrupt which will toggle the LED.

Comment: Ah... yeah, even I can see that a timer interrupt that will toggle the LED. The part will not use any UART. Iam randomly trying some example projects available and in one of that I saw in the comment section that the LED0 will toggle for LIN transmission. But it is just a timer interrupt that will toggle the LED.

Comment: Here is the part that uses UART, `vector_number = INT_UART0 -16;
     NVIC_ICPR |= 1 << (vector_number%32);                                                  NVIC_ISER |= 1 << (vector_number%32); inside the main function.

Comment: Can you give more information on your hardware setup?

Comment: I am using freescale TRK-KEA board with KEAZN64AMLH microcontroller on it. It supports LIN

Comment: Do you have a debugger that will allow you to put a breakpoint in the ISR to confirm that it is this particular code that is being executed?

Comment: Yeah I have. Okay where should I put

Comment: @j.aug, put a breakpoint on the LED0_TOGGLE line.  If the debugger stops here, obviously the Interrupt Service Routine is being executed when you are not expecting it to.

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible that the interrupt is actually being triggered. Does your interrupt pin have a pull up or pull-down resistor attached? If it’s disconnected and just “floating”, electrical noise in the environment can cause spurious interrupts.